# Extract word substring from NSString at given index

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsstring, substring

I want to pull out a substring from an NSString at a given index. Example:

```
NSString = @"Hello, welcome to the jungle";
int index = 9;
```

Index point '9' is in the middle of the word 'welcome', and I would like to be able to extract that word 'welcome' as a substring. Can anyone tell me how I would achieve this? With a regex?

Comment: you want 'e' or 'welcome' ?

Comment: I want the word 'welcome'

Comment: Isnt this question an invalid one? Why anyone would go to find with regex or nsset? it can be find quite easily with nsstring class' methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution as a category on NSString:

```
- (NSString *) wordAtIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    __block NSString *result = nil;
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                          usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                              if (NSLocationInRange(index, enclosingRange)) {
                                  result = substring;
                                  *stop = YES;
                              }
                          }];
    return result;
}
```

And another, which is more complicated but lets you specify exactly the word characters you want:

```
- (NSString *) wordAtIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    if (index < 0 || index >= self.length)
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException
                    format:@"Index out of range"];

    // This definition considers all punctuation as word characters, but you
    // can define the set exactly how you like
    NSCharacterSet *wordCharacterSet =
    [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    // 1. If [self characterAtIndex:index] is not a word character, find
    // the previous word. If there is no previous word, find the next word.
    // If there are no words at all, return nil.
    NSInteger adjustedIndex = index;
    while (adjustedIndex < self.length &&
           ![wordCharacterSet characterIsMember:
            [self characterAtIndex:adjustedIndex]])
        ++adjustedIndex;
    if (adjustedIndex == self.length) {
        do
            --adjustedIndex;
        while (adjustedIndex >= 0 &&
               ![wordCharacterSet characterIsMember:
                [self characterAtIndex:adjustedIndex]]);
        if (adjustedIndex == -1)
            return nil;
    }

    // 2. Starting at adjustedIndex which is a word character, find the
    // beginning and end of the word
    NSInteger beforeBeginning = adjustedIndex;
    while (beforeBeginning >= 0 &&
           [wordCharacterSet characterIsMember:
            [self characterAtIndex:beforeBeginning]])
        --beforeBeginning;

    NSInteger afterEnd = adjustedIndex;
    while (afterEnd < self.length &&
           [wordCharacterSet characterIsMember:
            [self characterAtIndex:afterEnd]])
        ++afterEnd;

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(beforeBeginning + 1,
                                afterEnd - beforeBeginning - 1);
    return [self substringWithRange:range];
}
```

The second version is also more efficient with long strings, assuming the words are short.

Comment: so this is good thanks, although if index is at the end/start of a word, it returns null I guess because it's not in range. Any way to adapt it slightly for that case?

Comment: sorry, it does work - my bad. However, if the word starts with a # or @ it doesn't register the @ or # - are they missed because of NSStringEnumerationByWords ?

Comment: I made one edit, changing `NSLocationInRange(index, substringRange)` to `NSLocationInRange(index, enclosingRange)` which should make it return a word even if you land on a word boundary. I'll peek at the @ or # case – would you give me an example and tell me what output you want?

Comment: I'm trying to output #name from "Hello #name how are you", but I only get "name"... does that make sense?

Comment: I posted another version. You might need to adjust it if you don't want periods commas, quotes, etc. considered word characters. Fun exercise.

Comment: this is great, thanks a lot I really appreciate your hard work!

Comment: So @noa one slight issue, it still returns the word if the cursor is after a line space, example: "hello " If cursor is at the point after the line space, 'hello' is still returned.

Comment: Sure, I wrote it that way on purpose. What do you want, nil? To accomplish that you can replace the entire block of code between `// 1.` and `// 2.` with an if statement.

Comment: Yup wanted it to be nil if the cursor wasn't on a word.. I can figure it out though thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather hackish way to do it, but it would work:

NSString has a method:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator;
```

so you could do:

```
NSString *myString = @"Blah blah blah";
NSString *output = @"";
int index = 9;
NSArray* myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; // <-- note the space in the parenthesis

for(NSString *str in myArray) {
    if(index > [str length]) index -= [str length] + 1; // don't forget the space that *was* there
    else output = str;
}
```

Comment: I was lazy... I'll leave that for someone with more patience than myself.

Comment: Nice one :) liked your sense of humor

Comment: Using `-componentsSeparatedByString:` or `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` is a decent idea, but this code doesn't work. For your own example with index 9, it returns "Blah" instead of "blah". For OP's example, indexes within "Hello," return "welcome", and all other indexes return "Hello,".

Comment: @noa, you are totally correct!! Apparently what I was thinking and what my fingers were doing was totally different.  I accidentally flipped the ">" operator lol.  I'm mac-less as of right now, but I will test it in the morning.  Honestly though, I like your solution alot better... it can be gently squeezed into a codebase with minimal changes and no interruptions in flows of logic :)